# How to "Click" on the green arrow shown in image [SAP welcome screen]

Tags: excel, vba, scripting, sap-erp, sap-gui

I have written a code in Excel-VBA to start SAP GUI.

The code starts the SAP Logon screen:

[image]

It clicks on *ECP - ECC Production* and then this SAP welcome screen appears.

[image]

I am not sure how to code the VB to "Click" the green tick mark so that the SAP-GUI opens up.

Unfortunately the excel file in which I wrote the code is deleted so I am not able to share my work on this.

As far as I know, answer to this question is just a one-liner.

Any help (either from scratch or specific) will be appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you can do this in python, then you call your python function on VBA

Comment: You say "unfortunately [...] is deleted". And your mind was blown at the same time? Stack Overflow expects you to provide code to reproduce. If you did it once, you can do it again. Anyway, it's very easy to start the recording of manual actions, log in, click the icon, and stop the recording, and you may have a look at the recorded script, that's all.